# include metauml diagrams in different sizes

Tags: beamer, input, metauml

I have made some UML diagrams using metauml. They fit perfectly into a report, but I would also like to include them in a beamer presentation. Unfortunately, they are too wide to fit a slide.

I use `\include{diagram.tex}` in my report.

What are my options here? Do I need to somehow export the diagram in an bitmap format or am I missing something in metauml documentation?

Comment: Maybe a `\resizebox` could help? Can you show us the content of `diagram.tex`? Or include the pdf of your report with `\includegraphics` and crop the boarders? Or compile `diagram.tex` with the standalone class and include the resulting pdf?

Comment: `\resizebox` is what I was looking for. Shame on me for not finding that out alone and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the content of the included files looks like, this question is hard to answer, but to name a few possibilities:

- using `\resizebox` or similar to scale the content
- include the pdf of the report with `\includegraphics` and crop the boarders
- compile `diagram.tex` with the standalone class and include the resulting pdf